# How to change default '/' in breadcrumbs rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to change the default `'/'` in breadcrumb  with this line

```
<%= render_breadcrumbs :separator => ' >> ' %>
```

But i get this error

> undefined method `html_safe' for {:separator=>">>"}:Hash Did you mean? html_safe?'

I am using `breadcrumbs_on_rails` gem for rails

Comment: dit you try another character than >> ? also try with &gt;&gt;

Comment: It's a known issue https://github.com/weppos/breadcrumbs_on_rails/issues/69

Comment: yeah @peter i tried with space.. with '&gt;&gt' i get the same error